# Pagination in endless recycler view with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am working on Q/A app . I have successfully loaded questions from firebase . But I am not able to apply pagination from Firebase like database . And how to recognize that we have reached end of recycler view so that next few questions can loaded .

Comment: Can you post your code for adapter .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To recognize that we have reached end of `RecyclerView` you can use this class [EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e)

To load more next question, you should define one more field in `Question class` like number

```
public class Question {
    private int number; // it must unique and auto increase when you add new question
    ...
}
```

Then when you load questions from `FireBase` you can do like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD = 10;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    final List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();

    private int currentPage = 0;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // init and set layout manager for your RecyclerView
        ...
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(questionList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) { // when we have reached end of RecyclerView this event fired
                loadMoreData();
            }
        });
        loadData(); // load data here for first time launch app
    }

    private void loadData() {
        // example
        // at first load : currentPage = 0 -> we startAt(0 * 10 = 0)
        // at second load (first loadmore) : currentPage = 1 -> we startAt(1 * 10 = 10)
        mDatabase.child("questions")
                .limitToFirst(TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD)
                .startAt(currentPage*TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD)
                .orderByChild("number")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No more questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            currentPage--;
                        }
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Question question = data.getValue(Question.class);
                            questionList.add(question);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                   @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
    }

    private void loadMoreData(){
        currentPage++;
        loadData();
    }
}
```

[Here is my DEMO project](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/StackOverFlowDemo/tree/master/FirebaseRecyclerViewWithLoadmore)

Comment: What is the minimum API level supported by your class.

Comment: @RishabhMaurya from level 1

Comment: Ok I will implement that and then notify you .

Comment: @RishabhMaurya if you have problem, please check my DEMO at bottom. it may help

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I am writing a same code.. pagination is working well but it clears the previous data when perform pagination called.. i haven't written clear data list anywhere.. any suggestion please

Comment: @VishvaDave you can see inside my `onDataChange` code. I don't clear old data, I have added new data by `questionList.add(question);`. Do you do like me?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I have serching and delete function also..so do i need to do anything for that like need to set current page to 0 or something?

Comment: This `ValueEventListener` will listen to changes in the items related to current page only. What if any field or already downloaded items is changed or what if any of the already downloaded items is deleted? How do we listen to such changes?

Answer (score 1):

To check whether you have reached the bottom of the RecyclerView, you can use the onScrolled listener as below, the if condition here is important and it is defining when a user has reached to the bottom.

```
mRV.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                mTotalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                mLastVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!mIsLoading && mTotalItemCount <= (mLastVisibleItemPosition + mPostsPerPage)) {
                    getUsers(mAdapter.getLastItemId());
                    mIsLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Secondly, you can use `startAt` and `limitToFirst` methods to get questions in batches as shown below:

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child(Consts.FIREBASE_DATABASE_LOCATION_USERS)
                    .orderByKey()
                    .startAt(nodeId)
                    .limitToFirst(mPostsPerPage);
```

I have created an open source app that shows exactly how it is done. Please have a look: https://blog.shajeelafzal.com/2017/12/13/firebase-realtime-database-pagination-guide-using-recyclerview/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can create [Firebase Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) to your [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/matteo/firebase_recycleview/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java), using [`startAt`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAt(double)) and [`limitToFirst`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#limitToFirst(int)) to download records in batches.

The [`limitToFirst`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#limitToFirst(int)) page size would be increased by and event, such as a click or a [pull to refresh](http://guides.codepath.com/android/implementing-pull-to-refresh-guide).

Comment: I want the recyclerview to display progress bar when the next set of fixed item is being loaded from firebase .

Comment: You can show/dismiss the `SwipeRefreshLayout` calling `setRefreshing`.