# Firestore : Retrieve documents that are not exist in an array, based on geolocation and with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to achieve a query with Firestore to show to my main user, user nears to him that he hasn’t seen yet !
Let’s call that function « getNearUsers », and my main user « toto ».
Sorry for the long title I could not find a more specific yet meaningful title.

Here the document design : 
[image: user document]

Like Tinder Toto can swipe users, each swiped user is stored in Toto document, in an array of userId called « likes ». 
To make geopoints and location queryable, I use GeoFirestorejs in a Firebase Cloud Function. This allow me to query user based on their « lastLocation ».

Users location are updated then they use the app, so for the same user each call to « getNearUsers » can give me different users even if toto haven’t « swipe » no one.

Here the function :

```
export const nearToMe = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const firestore = admin.firestore();
  const collection = firestore.collection('users');
  let limitQuery =  collection.limit(50);
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  const geofirestore: GeoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(firestore);
  const geoUsersCollection: GeoCollectionReference = geofirestore.collection('users');
  const userDocs = await geoUsersCollection.where('userId', '==', userId).get();
  const user = userDocs.docs[0].data();
  const userLoc = user.lastLocation;
  const userLikes: Array<String> = user.likes;
  const matchList = Array<any>();
  if(req.body.startAfter){
      limitQuery = limitQuery.startAfter(req.body.startAfter);
  } 
  const query = new GeoQuery(limitQuery).near({
    center: new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(userLoc.latitude, userLoc.longitude),
    radius: 10000
  });
  const nearUsers = await query.get();
  nearUsers.docs.forEach(nearUser => {
    const nearUserId = nearUser.data().userId;
    if (userLikes.indexOf(nearUserId) < 0 && nearUserId != userId) {
        matchList.push(nearUser.data());
    }
  });
  res.send(matchList);
});
```

I want to limit the numbers of users returned by the function, but I can’t do that at query time because I do not know how many users my user has already « swipe » without getting the list of nears users first (based on the fact that in Firestore you can not find items that are NOT in an array, or not exist). And this is my problem.

If I want to display 10 near users to Toto, I have to query more to be able to have some users that Toto haven’t seen in it.
I could use a query cursor and save it to search users after this cursor, but like said earlier, the users list of « getNearUsers » can give me different users, the list won’t be the same, the order won’t be neither.

At T time, « getNearUsers » could return  User1, User4. So I get a cursor at User4. But at T+1, the func can return User2, User3, User 4… 
So the cursor will be useless because that’s won’t return 2 and 3. Right ?

And more Toto swipe users, more his list become big and more my query need to retrieve a large set of data to be sure to be able to display users to Toto, or as an alternative I could launch several times the query with a cursor until I get a proper numbers of users…But the issue remains the same.

I’m a bit lost, and still don’t know yet if this kind of needs/query is doable easily in Firestore.
If you think of a better Document Modeling, I’ll be happy to change it.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear; I think you're asking *I want to show a user other users that are near to them but are just outside a radius around the user*. If that's the case, you need to determine a radius around the user of who he can see, say a mile, and then create a 'about to see' radius of 1.5 miles. The difference will be the users in the .5 mile difference they are 'about to see'.

Comment: Hi, sorry if the question seems unclear. By no means I want to gets users outside a radius around user. I want people inside the radius, but people that my user hasn't seen yet, and limit the number of users returns (10). One of the issues is, that I can't limit the result to 10 users inside the query (not the cloud function), because the documents that are returned are about users that my user may has seen - or not. So I need to filter this list of users.
Each time he uses the app, this user fetch a list of users who may be full of peoples already seen.....

Comment: What part of my question made you think that I wanted "users that are near to them but are just outside a radius around the user" ? 
I'll fix my question if it is ambiguous.
Thanks !

Comment: Hmm. If the app was working correctly then *all* users that meet your criteria within a specified radius around the user will always been 'seen' - so there would never be users this user hadn't seen yet per the goal to *show my main user, user nears to him that he hasn’t seen yet*. GeoFirestore has three events; enter, exit and move - those would guarantee there would never be a situation where another user isn't seen yet - hence why I thought you may be referring users just outside the radius.

Comment: I don't see where GeoFirestore-js has these events, I'm not using the iOS/Android version but the javascript version. I'm using it inside a Cloud Function, the request is triggered when user go to a certain screen of my app, I do not record his moves.
Basically, user launch the app, that show users next to him. He choose if he wants to meet them or not. He launch the app again, I do not want that he sees the same result, so I store the people that he has choose to meet (or not).
The ordering of the request result in based on location, users won't be in the same order.