# Showing data serially from Firestore in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have many datas in my firestore. But I want to show 10 datas at a time in the recyclerView and when user will click a "Next" button, it will show the next 10 datas below previous data. "Next" button will be at the bottom again and until there is data in firestore, clicking "Next" button will do the same work.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592325/is-there-a-way-to-paginate-queries-by-combining-query-cursors-using-firestorerec/50692959)** out.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo

Comment: You're very welcome Bedar.

Comment: I have set a "Next" button but the button is not showing when I am loading the documents. I have set the button below my recyclerView.

Comment: I have set a "Next" button but the button is not showing when I am loading the documents. I have set the button below my recyclerView. @AlexMamo