# Firestore pagination not working at all with DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of 10 items.
I have an MVI pattern. When presenter receives event to load more data I pass over the last item visible to for the api so he knows where to start from. My api call looks accordingly:

```
override fun getItems(
    size: Long,
    from: Item?
): Single<List<Item>> =
    getDocumentSnapshot("items", from?.id)
        .flatMap { getItemsData(siz, it) }
        .onErrorResumeNext { getItemsData(size, null) }
```

`getDocumentSnapshot` returns the DocumentSnapshot for the last item. (I don't want to keep global/class reference of the last item). If `from == null` that means its the first page and there is no previous last item. So the Rx operators execute accordingly. Thos boils down the main part where I am trying to paginate data `getItemsData`:

```
    private fun getItemsData(
    size: Long,
    from: DocumentSnapshot?
): Single<List<Item>> =
    Single.create { emitter ->
        collectionReference("items")
            .orderBy("created")
            .startAfter(from)
            .limit(size)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null)
                    emitter.onSuccess(task.result!!.documents.map { snapshot ->
                        try {
                            snapshot.toObject(PojoItem::class.java)!!.toData()
                        } catch (ne: NullPointerException) {
                            throw DocumentParseException(ne, snapshot.id)
                        }
                    })
                else
                    emitter.onError(NoDocumentException(cause = task.exception))
            }
    }
```

The weird thing is, that I am not getting any results when pass `DocumentSnapshot` to the query. If I use certain value, in eg pass in `TimeStamp` when I order by `created` then it works as expected. I have debugged the code as much as I can, and I am receiving the snapshot no problemo. Did a workaround and created a global `var` variable to store the last document snapshot in when receiving results `lastVisible = task.result.documents.last()` but I reproduced the exact same result with it, 0 results.

NOTE: If I pass `startAfter(null)` it starts from the beginning, the nullable is meant to be.

Comment: In a simpler way, I think this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592325/is-there-a-way-to-paginate-queries-by-combining-query-cursors-using-firestorerec/50692959)** might help.

Comment: I may sound stupid saying this, but I have checked my code against that answer and it is the same.... or I have missed some detail, but I don't think so.